# Unhandled promise rejection with 'if else' instruction and dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

A new execution error happened after I updated my project's node modules.

I am testing (with DiscordJS) the following code:

```
if (msg.content === "!next") {
    msg.channel.send(tellDate()) ;
}
```

with tellDate() being:

```
function tellDate() {
    var myDate = ...// Initialize myDate as a correct Date
    if(isPast(myDate){
        // ...
    }
    else if(isFuture(myDate)){
        console.log("after call isFuture function");
        return `tellDate : test test`;
    }
}
```

`myDate` will be such as it enters the `isFuture()` test. Here is `isFuture()`:

```
function isFuture(d)
{
    console.log("entering isFuture function");
    const today = new Date();
    console.log("after declaring today");
    if(d.getFullYear() > today.getFullYear())
        return true;
    else if(d.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() && d.getMonth() > today.getMonth())
        return true;
    else if(d.getFullYear() === today.getFullYear() && d.getMonth() === today.getMonth() && d.getDate() > today.getDate())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But execution never reaches `isFuture()`:

```
(node:8380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 2): DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
(node:8380) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

However, if I change the "else if" by a "if" in `tellDate()`, it displays:

```
entering isFuture function
after declaring today
```

But it won't execute the dates comparisons (same error).

So:

1. Why do "if" and "else if" make a difference in `tellDate()`?
2. What's wrong with the date comparisons?

Comment: In the case of else if, isPast must be returning true, so isFuture never gets called.  When you change it to a separate if, isPast can return true and isFuture is still called.

Comment: That's true: in my case, myDate was actually past, so it entered `isPast()` (which doesn't return anything) and not `isFuture()`. I modified `isPast()` to take that case into account.

Answer (score 0):

Your message send by `msg.channel.send` can't be empty

```
if (msg.content === "!next") {
    const message = tellDate();
    if(message) msg.channel.send(message) ;
}
```

You can simple use `>` to compare dates

```
function isFuture(d)
{
    console.log("entering isFuture function");
    const today = new Date();
    console.log("after declaring today");
    return d > today;
}
```

Comment: That's right: I found out the message was eventually empty. I modified `tellDate()` so as it can never return an empty string, now it works again.